# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout in app using retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have a simple program that connect to an API and get some data from it.I use `Retrofit` library.There are two activity. `MainActivity` includes a `RecyclerView` that show data received from the server. If press any item,application go to `UserInfoActivity` and show detailed information of that item.My app when go `UserInfoActivity` crashed after a few seconds and don't show information. However `response` correctly received but the program gives an error
on `txtId.setText(user.getId)` line. The error is `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`
In fact my problem starts when call `Call<User> getUserInfo(@Path("id") int id);` in second Activity.

This is `MainActivity` code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    userRequest();
}

private void userRequest(){
    APIInterface apiInterface= APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    retrofit2.Call<ArrayList<User>> call= apiInterface.getUsers();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ArrayList<User>> call, Response<ArrayList<User>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                ArrayList<User> users = response.body();
                setupRecycelerView(users);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ArrayList<User>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("RETROFIT","response not successful");
        }
    });
}

private void setupRecycelerView(ArrayList<User> users){
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.RcyView);
    adapter=new RecycelerAdapter(this,users);
    linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

}
```

This is `onBindViewHolder` function of `RecycelerAdapter`.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final User user=values.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(user.getName());
    holder.txtPhone.setText(user.getPhone());
    final Intent intent=new Intent(context, UserInfoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("user",user);
    holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This is `UserInfoActivity` code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_info);
    txtId=findViewById(R.id.txtId);
    txtName=findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtPhone=findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    User user=(User)intent.getSerializableExtra("user");
    id=user.getId();
    userInfoRequest();
}
private void userInfoRequest(){
    APIInterface apiInterface= APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    retrofit2.Call<User> call= apiInterface.getUserInfo(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                User user=response.body();
                Log.e("MF","ON Response");
                Log.e("MF",user.getName());
                Log.e("MF",user.getPhone());
                txtId.setText(user.getId());
                txtName.setText(user.getName());
                txtPhone.setText(user.getPhone());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("MF","on failure");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please post full stacktrace of error @sarina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
adapter=new RecycelerAdapter(this,users);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Used `notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the `RecyclerView` that data changed-added and set the `Adapter` after `setLayoutManager`.

---

If this didn't help,  initialize the `RecyclerView` inside `onCreate` method and set the `Adapter` in `onResponse` with `runOnUiThread` like following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    //Do something on UiThread
                   ArrayList<User> users = response.body();
                   adapter=new RecycelerAdapter(this,users);
                   recyclerView.setAdapter(users);
                }
            });
```

Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and it should work then.

Comment: I do every four answers but my problem don't solve yet!

Comment: So, initialize the `RecyclerView` inside `onCreate` method and set the `Adapter` in `onResponse` after `ArrayList<User> users = response.body();` with `runOnUiThread`. It would work then. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error repeats.

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.np.retrofitarcademy, PID: 14983
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1468)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5051)
        at com.example.np.retrofitarcademy.UserInfoActivity$1.onResponse(UserInfoActivity.java:50)`

Comment: Oh, that’s another issue actually, would you add the logcat in your question and I’d vote to open the question? Please edit the title and content with the following logs. Issue comes from SetText gettext in your model i suppose. We might need to check that too

Comment: I still have the previous error. `No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Comment: That’s just a warning, issue seems to be the model.. **NotFoundException: String resource ID**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180040/discussion-between-sarina-and-w).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `setupRecycelerView` on the response of the Retrofit api call, the problem is that till the response comes the `RecyclerView` doesnt have an adapter or a layoutManager attached to itself, hence the error.

Instead, you can call the `setupRecycelerView` inside `onCreate` itself and then create a global object of the `Users` list. Something like this:

`private final ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList();`

This list would be empty and the adapter would be initialised with the same empty list, then when you get the response from the retrofit api, use:

`users.addAll(response.getBody());`

this will fill the contents and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to make the adapter reflect the updated contents.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you initialize RecyclerView when/if the response from server is successful.

Initialize it (call setupRecycelerView() ) in `onCreate()`. And change `adapter=new RecycelerAdapter(this,users);` to `adapter=new RecycelerAdapter(this);`

Make your RecycelerAdapter's constructor take one argument only (probably Context)
In your adapter, make a public method that sets the users.

```
public setUserData(ArrayList<User> users) {
    this.values = users;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Call `RecycelerAdapter.setUserData(users);` from Retrofit's response is successful.

Comment: I do every four answers but my problem don't solve yet!

Comment: Move `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` to the bottom of your `setupRecycelerView()` method

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setAdapter()` after `setLayoutManager()` in your `setupRecycelerView()`